# What is the difference between mutableStateOf and mutableStateListOf?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-android-extensions

While working with a `ViewModel` and a `List` stored in there, I usually followed this approach:

```
var characteristics by mutableStateOf(listOf<Characteristic>())
```

Then, I could assign data to the List or modify it, and the UI would recompose properly:

```
characteristics = issuesRepository.getCharacteristics()
characteristics = characteristics.plus(newCharacteristic)
```

However, I recently stumbled across several approaches containing the keyword `mutableStateListOf()`, and it then seems to be a common practice to split a List into two separate variables, like this:

```
private val _characteristic = mutableStateListOf<Characteristic>()
val characteristic: List<Characteristic> = _characteristic
```

How do these approaches differ, and is one of those considered best-practice or as a cleaner approach?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `mutableStateOf` you are creating an observable object. So, the recomposition will happen just if you assign a new instance to this state.
Let's say that you want that recomposition happens after add a new item to the list. In this case, you need to create a copy of this list, add the elemento to this copied list, and then assign the copied list to the state.

The `mutableStateListOf` creates an observable list. All operations you've done in this list (add, remove, update) will cause a recomposition.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it helps me a lot! So if I use `mutableStateListOf()`, what is the point of using the two different variables `characteristics` and `_characteristics`?

Comment: The motivation is encapsulation. Since `_characteristics` (the "_" in the beginning is just a convention) is private it can only be changed internally from the class which has this property, other classes can't change it. To expose this field, you should use `characteristics` (particularly, I would use `State<List<String>>` instead of `List<String>`) and use it wherever you want.

Comment: @nglauber please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76983814/how-i-can-implement-custom-search-bar-with-menu-icon-in-jetpack-compose and try to answer please