# Android Compose Recomposition is not triggered when adding items in a mutable list

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a list of files in a LazyColumn.
User can select multiple files in the list.
I have a button floating over that list.
The text of the button is "Archive n files" (where n is the number of selected files in the list)
I want the text of the button to change every time a file is selcted or unselected in the list.

I use a MutableState<MutableList> that containt the selected files

```
selections = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(mutableListOf()) }
```

When a user clic on a file in the displayed list, I add or remove an entry in `selections`

```
        if (row.isSelectedState.value) {
            selections.value.add(row.idConversation)
        } else {
            selections.value.remove(row.idConversation)
        }
```

The size of `selections` is used in the button text

```
   text =
   if (selections.value.size == 0)
      "Archive"
   else
      String.format("Archive %1$d conversations", selections.value.size)
```

The problem is that when we add or remove items in `selections` the text of the button doesn't change, the recomposition is not trigerred base on `selections.value.size`

I fixed this by using another state

```
selectionCount = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(selections.value.size) }
```

```
   text =
   if (selectionCount.value == 0)
      "Archive"
   else
      String.format("Archive %1$d conversations", selectionCount.value)
```

And update this state every time I add or remove an item in `selections`

```
        if (row.isSelectedState.value) {
            selections.value.add(row.idConversation)
        } else {
            selections.value.remove(row.idConversation)
        }
        selectionCount.value = selections.value.size
```

But I don't like this solution because I have to maintain another state and can forget to update it in futur code where we add or remove items in `selections`

What can I do for the recomposition of the button to be triggered after adding/removing items in `selections` ?

Comment: [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables) Caution: Using mutable objects such as ArrayList<T> or mutableListOf() as state in Compose causes your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app. Mutable objects that are not observable, such as ArrayList or a mutable data class, are not observable by Compose and don't trigger a recomposition when they change. Instead of using non-observable mutable objects, the recommendation is to use an observable data holder such as State<List<T>> and the immutable listOf().

Answer (score 2):

replace this:

```
selections = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(mutableListOf()) }
```

with this:

```
selections = rememberSaveable { mutableStateListOf<Selection>()}
```

Here is [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75019670/9881599) of difference between `mutableStateListOf` and `mutableStateOf`

Answer (score 0):

Create the selection list as

```
val selections = remember { mutableStateListOf<Selection>()}
```

Create a variable to save the size

```
var size = 0

LaunchedUnit(key=selections.size){
  size = selections.size  
}
```

this LaunchedEffect block will execute everytime selections.size changes,
use the size variable wherever you would like to display it.

Comment: Why the LaunchedEffect though? You can use `selections.size` directly.

Comment: @JanBína you said recomposition was not triggered, using LaunchedEffect there would be recomposition whenever the selections.size chages and assign the value to another variable size.

Comment: Using `mutableStateListOf` is enough, that Launched effect is useless