# How I can implement custom search bar with menu icon in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, menuitem, searchbar

I implement this successfully
[image: Search app bar]

After that I want to implement custom search bar with menu icon like this on `TopAppBar` and no suggest strings needed, but this custom search bar not created by me

[image: Search app bar]

Please help

> MenuSearchBar.kt

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomSearchView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String,
    onTextChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onCloseClick: () -> Unit,
    onSearchClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color(0XFF101921))

    ) {
        TextField(value = text,
            onValueChange = onTextChange,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                //containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                cursorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            ),
            placeholder = { Text("Search") },
            singleLine = true, keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Search),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSearch = { onSearchClick(text) }),
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Filled.Search,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.content_description_search)
                )
            },
            trailingIcon = {
                if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                            if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                                onTextChange("")
                            } else {
                                onCloseClick()
                            }
                        },
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Close,
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.content_description_close)
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

> HomeScreenView.kt

```kotlin
var mShowSearch by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var mTextSearch by remember { mutableStateOf(mHomeViewModel.searchQuery.value) }

if (mShowSearch) {
    MenuSearchBar(text = mTextSearch,
       onTextChange = { mTextSearch = it }) {
       mShowSearch = false
    }
}

@Composable
fun TopAppBarWithNavigationBar() {
     ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerSheet {
                NavShape(mCredit, mDebit)
                Spacer(Modifier.height(12.dp))
                mNavItemsList.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    //Spacer(Modifier.height(6.dp))
                    NavigationDrawerItem(
                        label = { Text(text = item.label) },
                        selected = index == mSelectedItems,
                        onClick = {
                            //navController.navigate(item.route)
                            mSelectedItems = index
                            mCoroutineScope.launch { mDrawerState.close() }
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, item.label, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = if (index == mSelectedItems) {
                                    item.selectedIcon
                                } else item.unselectedIcon,
                                contentDescription = item.contentDescription
                            )
                        },
                        badge = {
                            item.badgeCount?.let { Text(text = item.badgeCount.toString()) }
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }, drawerState = mDrawerState
    ){
        Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), topBar = {
            TopAppBar(title = {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.app_name),
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )
            }, navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    mCoroutineScope.launch { mDrawerState.open() }
                }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.content_description_menu)
                    )
                }
            }, actions = {
                IconButton(onClick = { mShowSearch = true }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search,
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.content_description_search)
                    )
                }
                val mAngle: Float by animateFloatAsState(
                    targetValue = if (mShowDropdownMenu) 180f else 0f,
                    label = stringResource(id = R.string.label_animate_sort_icon)
                )
                IconButton(onClick = { mShowDropdownMenu = !mShowDropdownMenu }) {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.rotate(mAngle),
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown,
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.content_description_sort)
                    )
                }
                DropdownMenu(expanded = mShowDropdownMenu,
                    onDismissRequest = { mShowDropdownMenu = false }) {
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.label_sort_by_name)) },
                        onClick = {
                            mHomeViewModel.updateSortOrder(SortOrder.BY_NAME)
                            mShowDropdownMenu = false
                        },
                        leadingIcon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Filled.SortByAlpha,
                                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.content_description_sort_by_name)
                            )
                        })
                    DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.label_sort_by_date_created)) },
                        onClick = {
                            mHomeViewModel.updateSortOrder(SortOrder.BY_DATE)
                            mShowDropdownMenu = false
                        },
                        leadingIcon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Filled.ChangeCircle,
                                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.content_description_sort_by_date)
                            )
                        })
                }
            }, scrollBehavior = mScrollBehavior
            )
        })
}
```

Comment: I implement this https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1NlK.jpg

Comment: But I need to implement like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/NES9Q.jpg

Comment: I also need answer of this question